# Inter-satellite/Inter-platform communication requirements

Tags: low-earth-orbit, geostationary, link-budget, bandwidth

I am studying Inter-satellite/Inter-platform links and would like to compute the link budget: Satellite-Satellite or HAP to HAP ( high altitude platform).

For my computation, I am looking for a document with link specifications in 5G or 6G communication.

In ITU regulation defined frequencies for the inter-satellite link (22.55-23.55 GHz, 24.45- 24.75 GHz, 32.0-33.0 GHz and 59.3-71.0 GHz), but I didn't find information about latency, bandwidth, power and etc.

I also can not find such regulations for altitude platforms. Does anyone know of there is a specification document for altitude platforms?

Is there a document where I can collect all information?

Comment: Does it have to actually be 5G or 6G protocols and technologies, or do you just want to specify a certain bandwidth. All that "G" stuff is for large, distributed networks of routers and large numbers of users in close proximity, and most satellite links it seems would involved phased array antennas electronically pointing at each other doing peer-to-peer single channel communication. I don't think a protocol for cell phones walking around in a crowded public space is a good model for inter-satellite communications, but I'm no expert and wow I could certainly be wrong!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such a document exists, because those things aren't regulated.  The carrier frequency ranges are regulated, but any signal that fits in the band is allowed.  There are no generic requirements for latency, bit error rate, modulation type, etc.  The only exception I know of is power, in that some parts of some frequency bands have limitations on the power of radiated signals, but in general the only way to avoid other people in your band stepping on you is clever signal processing, such as CDMA.

Comment: Don't forget, even if the inter-platform link per se is unregulated, any sidelobes that reach the ground would come under the same regulations as terrestrial or space r.f.